# Fazer múltiplas requisições ou apenas uma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em nodejs, onde constantemente são necessárias consultar informações no banco de dados, como por exemplo: nome, descrição de itens e etc... Um site similar seria a netflix, que consulta tais informações a cada vez que o usuário passa o mouse em um filme/série.

Porém gostaria de saber, se é melhor fazer uma requisição ao banco de dados cada vez que o usuário passar o mouse, ou ao carregar o site, salvar todo o banco de dados em uma session e chamar tais dados quando o usuário passar o mouse, no caso eu estaria usando socket.io para agilizar a resposta, porém não sei se tal prática exige muito do servidor. Então fica a pergunta:

- Fazer um único select no banco de dados ou armazenar tudo em uma session?

ou

- Enviar requisições diversas cada vez que necessário (quase sempre)?

Answer (score 2):

A primeira opção não vai escalar, não vai ser possível ter no cliente toda a base de dados quando ela for grande demais.

Porem a segunda opção de fazer um pedido ajax a cada `mouseover` pode ser demasiado dispendioso. Pode até ser a solução ideal, porém eu sugiro um meio termo:

Se o mouse vai passar em cima de algo (imagem, ou titulo de texto), parece-me que seria possível já ter com essa informação mais meta-data que pudesse ser usada no cliente. Por exemplo, se vais fazer `hover` sobre imagens e queres ter o título, podes trazer já do servidor quando a imagem é montada o titulo também. Depois quando houver clique na imagem vais precisar de mais dados, aí sim viria o pedido ao servidor para completar com a informação específica relacionada com essa imagem.

Porém, se no hover precisas de ter todos os dados relacionados que há na base de dados, e não há outro passo onde vais precisar de mais dados então não será viável a solução A ou B. Nesse caso escolhe uma e testa.

Comment: Vou tentar criar algo meio termo, ou ao menos carregar o minimo possível de dados ao iniciar sem haver necessidades de fazer tantas requisições.